# How to provide option to show plugin in selected menus page?

Tags: wordpress

I am using a plugin in wordpress but it does not provide a option to which page i what to show that plugin.
What i done? I am showing you.Firstly i get menus names through this wordpress function:

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'main-menu',
    'depth'           => 1,
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

It shows menus like this:

[image]

Comment: please be more specific about your question, this i a little vague.  are you looking for a full solution for theme / plugin options?

Comment: @pushplaybang: Thanks for your reply. Actually i want if someone tell me how can i do this so that its very grateful to me.

Answer (score 0):

While I feel like your question is incredibly incomplete, and I'm not sure of your technical level, I would highly recommend using one of two frameworks to create the options panel for the plugin.

They will provide an easy way to work with the settings api and create various field types etc.

have a look at the [Redux framework](https://github.com/reduxframework/redux-framework) or at [CMB](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/wiki/Using-CMB-to-create-an-Admin-Theme-Options-Page)